# sqlite3 rawquery update does not work

Tags: android, sqlite

Tried everything. This UPDATE don't work. No error or something - it just not updates the table.

```
   void SetDisable (Integer ID, boolean action){
       Integer s;
       if (action==true) s = 0; else s = 1;
       db.rawQuery("UPDATE sms SET disabled="+s+" WHERE id="+ID+"",null);  
   }
```

This is my table schema:

```
CREATE TABLE sms (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, fromhour INT, frommin INT, tohour INT, tomin INT, disabled INT);
sqlite>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's easy to use the update method provided by the SQLiteDatabase class.

```
void SetDisable (Integer ID, boolean action){
    Integer s;
    if (action==true) s = 0; else s = 1;

    ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
    cv.put(disabled, s);

    String where = "id=?";
    String[] whereArgs = {Integer.toString(ID)};

    db.update(sms, cv, where , whereArgs);   
}
```

Comment: yes it is easy to use update method for SQLiteDataBase but in case if you want to update the whole record. If you want to update only single or just a couple of fields, the best way is to use simple execSQL method. If you try to update single field with rawQuery it wouldn't update, that's why just use execSQL().

Answer (score 11):

**Try this:**

```
 db.execSQL("UPDATE sms SET disabled="+s+" WHERE id="+ID+"");
```

SQL queries which return a table (a cursor) are to be run with rawQuery, and those that do not return tables are to be run with execSQL

**See this:**

[Increase the value of a record in android/sqlite database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3427516/increase-the-value-of-a-record-in-android-sqlite-database)

Comment: You can use new Object[]{} (empty array of Objects) as your bind args if you don't have anything to replace in the query. Not sure if that will fully solve the problem. There is a different form of execSQL that takes args if you need those.

Comment: This is the correct answer, and it saved me many more hours to waste. I was using rawQuery() on my UPDATE. I also didn't want to trigger ContentObserver, so couldn't use the ContentProvider either. My table is pretty big, and I wanted to UPDATE all the rows first before calling notifyChange(), whereas ContentObserver calls notifyChange() on every single row update, which is a pretty bad design in my case.

Comment: It's awful, that SQLite does not fire any warning in such cases and update is just suppressed silently.

Answer (score -1):

**Updated:**

Try this

```
ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
cv.put("disabled", s);

db.update("table_name", cv, "id="+ID, null);
```

NOTE: I don't know if it is enough to put ONLY what you need to change in cv or you HAVE TO put all the attributes.

Comment: @StErMi: My bad. I read it "must be ; terminated". Should I delete this?

Comment: Does'nt work either. Got warning: "Found SQL string that ends in ;"

Comment: iturki yes maybe it's better :) @Dikobraz as I said (and as documentation is saying), you have NOT to put the semicolon at the end of the query

Comment: @Dikobraz : I don't know if this is correct or not but if I were you I will try to inclose the `s` with single quotation.

Comment: Tried. Maybe anybody can rewrite my rawquery() to db.update() ?