# Update table using rawQuery() method does not work

Tags: android, sqlite

I tried the following SQLite query:

```
    int idServizo = 150;
    String whereClause = id_servizio+" = '"+idServizio+" ' ";
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put("sync", 1);

    int r = dbManager.updateTable("myTable", cv, whereClause);
```

Where fields sync and id_servizio are both integer.
The method updateTable is:

```
 public int updateTable(String table, ContentValues values, String whereClause){
    int r = mDb.update(table, values, whereClause, null);
    return r;
}

 // mDb is SQLiteDatabase object
```

All this works good. 
But if I try this with the rawQuery() method:

```
 public Cursor RawQuery(String sqlQuery, String[] columns){
    return mDb.rawQuery(sqlQuery, columns);    
}
```

The table is not updated! even if no error occurs.

```
 int idServizo = 150;
 String updateQuery ="UPDATE myTable SET sync = 1 WHERE id_servizio = "+idServizio;
 dbManager.RawQuery(updateQuery, null);
```

Why does this not work?

Comment: For those who are still looking, this is the way I made it work for the similar problem. See this [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9798527) by Akhil

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Problem solved.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html

Can't works because `rawQuery` runs the provided SQL and returns a `Cursor` over the result set.

If I want to return a table I have to use `rawQuery`, otherwise no!

[Increase the value of a record in android/sqlite database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3427516/increase-the-value-of-a-record-in-android-sqlite-database)

Answer (score 46):

This is because when a rawQuery is executed cursor is returned. Without the call to `cursor.moveToFirst()` and `cursor.close()` the database won't get updated.

```
int idServizo = 150;
String updateQuery ="UPDATE myTable SET sync = 1 WHERE id_servizio = "+idServizio;
Cursor c= dbManager.rawQuery(updateQuery, null);

c.moveToFirst();
c.close();
```

I dont know the need to call moveToFirst() but this works fine and the database gets updated.

Comment: Saved my day . Thanks

Comment: Works like a charm!

Comment: Spend multiple hours trying to figure out what I was doing wrong. Thanks, this answer saved my day.

Comment: Great. Was scratching my head on this one. That explains it.

Comment: Use `db.execSQL()` instead of `db.rawQuery()`.

Comment: Whaaaat, really?! The db won't get updated unless you do cursor.moveToFirst()? This ought to be in the documentation! Which currently says "Runs the provided SQL", not "Runs the provided SQL if or when you move through the returned cursor." Thank you for this answer!

Comment: @LoMaPh The doc (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase#execSQL(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object[])) says not to use `execSQL()` with an UPDATE statement.

Answer (score 5):

You should use db.execSQL() instead db.rawQuery().

Answer (score 4):

Instead of doing this:

```
Cursor c= dbManager.RawQuery(updateQuery, null);
c.moveToFirst();
c.close();
```

You just need this:

```
dbManager.execSQL(updateQuery, null);
```

### ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

Posting answer because sometimes many people (like me) not reading comments.
Most popular answer is not correct but [Yaqub Ahmad's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/265167/yaqub-ahmad) comment is correct.

Answer from [CommonsWare](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115145/commonsware) explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29591319/insert-in-method-rawquery-does-not-work):

> rawQuery() is for SQL statements that return a result set. Use
>   execSQL() for SQL statements, like INSERT, that do not return a result
>   set.

### ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

[Documentation for execSQL:](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#execSQL(java.lang.String))

```
public void execSQL (String sql)
```

**Execute a single SQL statement that is NOT a SELECT or any other SQL statement that returns data.**

[Documentation for rawQuery:](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase#rawQuery(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[]))

```
public Cursor rawQuery (String sql, 
                String[] selectionArgs)
```

**Runs the provided SQL and returns a Cursor over the result set.**

Comment: If you mean that https://stackoverflow.com/a/27483015/423105 is not correct, please cite your source. While I have lots of respect for CommonsWare, `execSQL()` is problematic because the documentation for one of its signatures says "Execute a single SQL statement that is NOT a SELECT/INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE" (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase#execSQL(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object[]))

Comment: There's no clear reason why the aforementioned restriction on `execSQL(String sql, Object[] bindArgs)` wouldn't also apply to `execSQL(String sql)`, and in any case, bindArgs are often needed.

Answer (score 2):

Your `update` call formats the ID as string, while the `rawQuery` call formats is as number.

Assuming that the ID in the table indeed is a string, use:

```
String updateQuery = "UPDATE myTable SET sync = 1 WHERE id_servizio = '" + idServizio + "'";
```

Comment: This error is not present in my code. I made a mistake asking question.

Comment: why the -1 ? the suggested solution seems legit, if not correct

Comment: The REAL issue here is `mDb.rawQuery()` NOT the updateQuery, for UPDATE he need to use `execSQL()` instead of `rawQuery()`.